# Python sparse matrix remove duplicate indices except one?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am computing the cosine similarity between matrix of vectors, and I get the result in a sparse matrix like this:

> - (0, 26)   0.359171459261
> - (0, 25)   0.121145761751
> - (0, 24)  0.316922015914
> - (0, 23)  0.157622038039
> - (0, 22)  0.636466644041
> - (0, 21)  0.136216495731
> - (0, 20)  0.243164535496
> - (0, 19)  0.348272617805
> - (0, 18)  0.636466644041
> - (0, 17)  1.0

But there are duplicates for example:

> (0, 24) 0.316922015914 and (24, 0) 0.316922015914

What I want to do is to remove them by indice and be (if I have (0,24) then I don't need (24, 0) because it is the same) left with only one of this and remove the second, for all vectors in the matrix.
Currently I have the following code to create the matrix:

```
vectorized_words = sparse.csr_matrix(vectorize_words(nostopwords,glove_dict))
cos_similiarity = cosine_similarity(vectorized_words,dense_output=False)
```

So to summarize I don't want to remove all duplicates, I want to be left with only one of them using the pythonic way.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Where do `vectorize_words` and `cosine_similarity` come from?  It is probably easier to remove the 'duplicates' while generating `cos_similarity`, than to remove them from the matrix after.  `sparse` matrices aren't designed for individual element manipulations.

Comment: `scipy.spatial.distance.squareform` converts to/from a compact upper_triangle form that eliminates duplicates.  I don't know if there's a version that works with sparse matrices.

Comment: @hpaulj cosine_similarity comes from sklearn, and vectorize words is my function to get each word vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is easiest to get the upper-triangle of a `coo` format matrix:

First make a small symmetric matrix:

```
In [876]: A = sparse.random(5,5,.3,'csr')
In [877]: A = A+A.T
In [878]: A
Out[878]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 11 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [879]: A.A
Out[879]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.81388978,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.73944395,  0.20736975,  0.98968617],
       [ 0.81388978,  0.73944395,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.20736975,  0.        ,  0.05581152,  0.04448881],
       [ 0.        ,  0.98968617,  0.        ,  0.04448881,  0.        ]])
```

Convert to `coo`, and set the lower-triangle data values to 0

```
In [880]: Ao = A.tocoo()
In [881]: mask = (Ao.row>Ao.col)
In [882]: mask
Out[882]: 
array([False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,
        True,  True], dtype=bool)
In [883]: Ao.data[mask]=0
```

Convert back to 0, and use `eliminate_zeros` to prune the matrix.

```
In [890]: A1 = Ao.tocsr()
In [891]: A1
Out[891]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 11 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [892]: A1.eliminate_zeros()
In [893]: A1
Out[893]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [894]: A1.A
Out[894]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.81388978,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.73944395,  0.20736975,  0.98968617],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.05581152,  0.04448881],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Both the `coo` and `csr` formats have a in-place `eliminate_zeros` method.

---

```
def eliminate_zeros(self):
    """Remove zero entries from the matrix

    This is an *in place* operation
    """
    mask = self.data != 0
    self.data = self.data[mask]
    self.row = self.row[mask]
    self.col = self.col[mask]
```

Instead of using `Ao.data[mask]=0` you could this code as a model for eliminating just the lower_triangle values.

Comment: Wont "eliminate_zeros" remove all zeros? I mean I might have a 0 value somewhere which is from the original matrix and it will delete it as well?

Comment: Yes it will.  I'll add the code for the `coo` `eliminate_zeros`, in case you want to adapt it to work directly with `mask`.

Comment: Thank you very much